# How to call controller action and then render it to a string in ror?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to call controller action and then render in to a string from "outside" in ror?

```
class SomeService
  controller = UsersController.new
  # need to call an index action
  # data = controller.render_to_string 
end
```

Comment: possibly helpful: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try this with the new **Rails 5**, where **rendering views from outside controllers** [is possible and supported](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/new-feature-in-rails-5-render-views-outside-of-actions). Rails 5 is currently in beta, so in a few weeks it should be [released officially](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/).

I have no idea how to achieve a similar thing in earlier Rails versions.